# Filter in serial order for Birt tables

Tags: filtering, birt

I have a table in a Birt report where I want to display the bottom 10 processing times of a customer process. A simple "Bottom n" filter did the trick very well - but here comes my costumer. He stated that he wants the bottom 10 table like I created, but without discordant values which are produced by single processes which run only like once a month.

So the table should display the bottom 10 processing times, but it should only contain processes if the specific process makes more than, let's say 0.01 % of the overall run processes in a month.

I tried an additional filter that only shows processes which run more often than 0.01 % of the total processes - but now my result table is empty.

Is it possible to achieve that **Birt filters first** all processes out which are processed less than 0.01 % of the total amount of processes and **after that** builds a bottom 10 list of the pre-filtered result set? It is not possible for me to change the SQL data set because it is used in some other tables, too.

Here are my filters which work fine if I apply only one of them - both together I receive an empty result set.

```
<list-property name="filter">
  <structure>
    <property name="operator">ge</property>
    <expression name="expr" type="javascript">row["TOTAL"]/row["Ov_TOTAL"]</expression>
    <simple-property-list name="value1">
      <value>0,01</value>
    </simple-property-list>
    <property name="updateAggregation">true</property>
  </structure>
  <structure>
    <property name="operator">bottom-n</property>
    <expression name="expr" type="javascript">row["AVG_DURATION"]</expression>
    <simple-property-list name="value1">
      <value>10</value>
    </simple-property-list>
    <property name="updateAggregation">true</property>
  </structure>
</list-property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try and it works for me. The only difference with your example is, in my case the ratio is already computed when the filter is applied: see "shareVolume" column below.

```
<list-property name="filter">
    <structure>
        <property name="operator">ge</property>
        <expression name="expr" type="javascript">row["shareVolume"]</expression>
        <simple-property-list name="value1">
            <value>0.01</value>
        </simple-property-list>
        <property name="updateAggregation">true</property>
    </structure>
    <structure>
        <property name="operator">bottom-n</property>
        <expression name="expr" type="javascript">row["value2"]</expression>
        <simple-property-list name="value1">
            <value>3</value>
        </simple-property-list>
        <property name="updateAggregation">true</property>
    </structure>
</list-property>
```

To achieve this i computed the ratio in the dataset. I just added two computed columns: the SQL is unchanged and other existing report components using the same dataset still perfectly work.

[image]

Comment: The computed columns did the trick in combination with the replacement of "0,01" to "0.01". In my next life, I hope we all use the same language, the same charset, same standards and all live in the same time zone. I don't know how many hours I have spent on things like that ...